# How to set the language of javac in English permanently in eclipse

Tags: java

I installed the JDK SE8, and the javac compiler messages are in russian.

I tried everything but it can't be changed. Somebody help me. Thanks

Comment: please be a bit more concrete about "I tried everything" - what exactly have you tried? What does your setup look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try passing this argument: `-J-Duser.language=en`.

To set it permanently in the windows registory `: REG ADD "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /v JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS /d -Duser.language=en /t REG_SZ /f`

For other operating systems - set it as an environment variable using your preferred method.